# Twitter API: Search followers tweets

Tags: twitter

Is there any way to search for a term within a user's followers' tweets only. Search API is global, apparently. I want to search only within the user's followers.

Is there a way of doing this. Even a hugely complex one will be appreciated.

Comment: Has any progress been made to the Twitter API in the last 4 years to allow for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve the IDs of the user's followers with `GET http://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?screen_name=<username>`. Each ID corresponding to a user, you can now download the tweets of each follower with `GET http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=<follower ID>`. I recognize that it requires lots of requsets to the Twitter API (which are rate limited) but you cannot do better with this API.